# What should I insert into html so it is ok in code validators?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script>

function run(){
    var div = document.createElement('div')
    div.style.position = 'absolute'
    div.style.left = 0
    div.style.top = 0
    div.onmouseover=function(){
        alert('mo')
        this.style.opacity = 0
    }
    div.style.width = 30
    div.style.height = 30
    div.style.backgroundColor = '#000'
    document.body.appendChild(div)
}

onload = run
</script>
<title></title>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```

This hmtl runs ok in quirks mode.
But, I know that I need to use some other tags for the html.

I´d like to know...
1 - What other tags should I add, so it runs ok in code validator?

2 - Why my javascript it´s not working with the html5 doctype? (It works ok in quirks mode)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must specify a [units](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Units) designator for height and width.  Eg: `cm`, `mm`, `in`, `pt`, `pc`, `px`, `em`, `en`, `ex`, `ch`, `rem`, `vh`, `vw`, `vmin`, or `vmax`.

```
div.style.width = "30px";
div.style.height = "30px";
```

Without a units designator, your values have no effect and the div takes up no space on the page.

Also, while the rest of your JavaScript is technically valid, it would be nice to see semi-colons at the end of each statement.  But, perhaps that's just my personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

> I got 3 warnings. And if you test the html, my div doesn´t appear. – Marcelo Noronha

To get rid of the two character encoding warnings, you will need to declare a character encoding in your `head` tag, via the `meta` tag.  An example of such is as follows (for using UTF-8):

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   ...
</head>
```

The third warning you are getting is because the W3 validator is essentially warning you that HTML5 is still in progress, and therefore your validation results may change in the future.

To get your `div` to appear (which has no relation to the validation of your HTML), see gilly3's answer about specifying a unit for your width and height properties.